# Raymarching artifacts

Tags: opengl, glsl, raycasting

I was playing with raymarching using distance fields in GLSL sandbox and got stuck with a strange problem with artifacts.

Click [here](http://glsl.heroku.com/e#1102.3) and take a look at the spheres generated in corners, they have strange artifacts plus they "flicker".

Is the `mod` operator, for domain repetition the culprit here?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that `mod` operator is the source of artifacts, at least in the general case. Recently I also experimented with raymarching of distance fields and all worked pretty fine. Check my screens lower. My trusty guide in this stuff are tutorials and papers of Iñigo Quílez. If you don`t know about this guy, taste his [strawberry](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/index.htm). More concretely: [iterative shapes](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/menger/menger.htm), [distance functions](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm) and [raymarching distance fields](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/raymarchingdf/raymarchingdf.htm).

[image][image]